# About "natural proof" of Razborov and Rudich

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computer-science, computability-theory

The famous "Natural Proof" paper ,http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/natural.pdf , ‎of Razborov and Rudich gives a barrier for any proof that try to separate P and NP. It mainly shows that if there is a high enough "hard" pseudo-randomness generator then there is no "natural proof" that can give the super-polynomial lower bounds of circuit complexity for any problem. The rigorous statement is as follows:

[image: $]

I don't understand the final part of the proof of Razborov and Rudich's 'natural proof'. I use Timothy Chow's paper 'Almost natural proof". The argument goes as follows

[image]

It is essentially the same as the proof of Razborov and Rudich. You can simply ignore the slightly modified part. It says " **we obtain a statistical test that distinguishes between $G_k(x(u))$ and $(x(u'),x(u''))$"**, but actually, for $G_k(x(u))$, we obtained our function$ f_i$ as described in the proof, but for$ (x(u'),x(u''))$ we have to firstly transform it into $(G_k(x(u')),G_k(x(u'')))$, then construct a function $f_{i-1
}$ as in the proof, then use $C_n$.  In other words, we don't formally have the same construction for $(x(u'),x(u''))$ as $(G_k(x(u))$. So even if they use the same $C_n$, but the construction from $G_k(x(u))$ to function $f_i$ and the construction from $(x(u'),x(u''))$ to function$ f_{i-1}$ are completely different, so finally they actually use different circuits.

Could anyone give some guidance about this point?

Thanks!

Comment: You should state the theorem whose proof you're asking about.  Also, use the appropriate markup to render mathematical expressions, e.g. instead of f_(i-1) do $f_{i-1}$.